# CSS Dropdown Menu - not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

Hey I have a CSS dropdown menu that drops down on hover. Unfortunately its not aligned correctly, directly under "services", but to the right of it.

How would I change it so its aligned correctly? I've been slowly adding and modifying free CSS templates to make a custom website, as I'm no coder and this is all kinda new. I'm a visual learner, so messing around until I can understand it and my way of learning..but for some reason I just can't figure this out, even after reading a bunch and thinking I had it correct.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```css
.navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.site-header-white .navbar-nav>li>a,
.site-header-white .site-title {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.nav .open>a,
.nav .open>a:focus,
.nav .open>a:hover,
.navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-nav>li>a:focus,
.navbar-nav>li.active>a,
.navbar-collapse li a:hover,
.dropdown.open>a,
.site-header-white .dropdown.open>a,
.dropdown-menu a:hover,
.dropdown:hover>a,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu li a:hover,
.slicknav_nav>li.active a,
.slicknav_open .slicknav_arrow,
.slicknav_nav>li a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #f13a11;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-toggle[aria-expanded=true] {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar,
.navbar-toggle[aria-expanded=true] .icon-bar {
  background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  display: inline;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 0;
  min-width: 130px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #f13a11;
  top: 140%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover+.dropdown-menu,
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GG's Aerial Photography</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav-link smoothScroll">Home</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link smoothScroll">About Us</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#class" class="nav-link smoothScroll" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
            <li><a href="services.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Real Estate</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Construction</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Damage</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link smoothScroll">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>




      <ul class="social-icon ml-lg-3">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **dropright** class form bootstrap Framework

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#class" class="nav-link smoothScroll dropright" data-toggle="dropdown">Services</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                    <li><a href="services.html">Events</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Real Estate</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Construction</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog.html">Damage</a></li>
                                </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried using dropright and it didn't seem to do anything at all actually. If you'd like, you can take a peek at the website and see whats going on yourself. www.ggsaerialphotography.com

Answer (score 0):

Herewith I have provided a sample reference with your code for dropdown

```html
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {}

</style>

.

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
 

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GG's Aerial Photography</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#home" class="nav-link smoothScroll">Home</a>
        </li>


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link smoothScroll">About Us</a>
        </li>
       
       
       <div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn">Services</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="services.html">Event</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Real Estate</a>
    <a href="blog.html">Construction</a>
  </div>
</div>

        
        


        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link smoothScroll">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>




      <ul class="social-icon ml-lg-3">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```